# Middleware interfering on session messages

Tags: php, laravel

I am developing a dashboard and I am trying to handle the errors, for this I have this code on handler.php

```
public function render($request, Throwable $e)
{        

    if($e instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException)
    {
        if(Auth::user() && (Auth::user()->isStaff() || Auth::user()->isAdmin()))
        {
            return response()->view('dashboard.404error', [], 404);
        }
        return response()->view('404error', [], 404);
    }
    elseif ($e instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException) {
        return response()->view('405error', [], 405);
    }
    // elseif($this->isHttpException($e) && $e->getStatusCode() == '405')
    // {
    //     return response()->view('404error', [], 404);
    // }
    return parent::render($request, $e);  
}
```

But to check if the user is logged and what type it is, I have to add this middleware on kernel.php:

Middleware:

```
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
```

But I dont know why after that my pop ups stop appering when I edit a staff or create one and I dont know why.

[image]

Normally on views I return them with something like this:

```
return redirect()->route('admin.operadoras')
->with('alert-msg', 'Staff edited with success')
->with('alert-type', 'danger');
```

And what I have on blade view is this:

```
@if (session('alert-msg'))
            @include('partials.message')
@endif
```

I dont know why that middleware, interfer with this messages.